# Calling Web Service method throwing Remote Disconnected error in Zeep

Tags: web-services, maximo, zeep

I am using the Python Zeep library to call Maximo web services and able to fetch the WSDL without any issues. When I am trying to query using one of the method in Web service, it is throwing error

**requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))**

```
 multiasset_wsdl = "http://maximoqa.xyz.com:9080/meaweb/services/MULTIASSET?wsdl"
    work_order = 'NA0000211'
     # set the session
    session = Session()
    session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(Username, Password)
    session.verify = False
    transport = Transport(session=session)  
    settings = Settings(strict=False ,force_https = False)
    maximo_multiasset_client = Client(multiasset_wsdl, transport=transport, settings=settings
    multiasset_type_factory = maximo_multiasset_client.type_factory('ns0')
    mult_asset_query = multiasset_type_factory.QueryMULTIASSETType(
                baseLanguage = "?",
                creationDateTime = tt.get_now(),                
                maximoVersion = "?",
                maxItems = "1",
                messageID = "?",
                rsStart = "0",
                transLanguage = "EN",
                uniqueResult = False,
                MULTIASSETQuery = multiasset_type_factory.MULTIASSETQueryType
                (
                    operandMode = multiasset_type_factory.OperandModeType('AND'),
                    orderby = "?",
                    WHERE = f"WONUM='{work_order}'",
                    WORKORDER = None
                )            
            )
        print('Calling Query MultiAsset')     
        query_response = maximo_multiasset_client.service.QueryMULTIASSET(mult_asset_query)
```

Appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Try setting baseLanguage to "EN"

Comment: Still the same error.